# Como fazer for loop em SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, pl-sql

```
BEGIN
 <<LOOP_EXTERNO>>
 FOR V_EXTERNO IN 1..20 LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Contador externo: ' || V_EXTERNO);
  <<LOOP_INTERNO>>
   FOR V_INTERNO IN 1..5 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Contador interno: ' || V_INTERNO);
    IF V_EXTERNO = 10 THEN
     EXIT LOOP_EXTERNO;
    END IF;
  END LOOP INTERNO;
 END LOOP EXTERNO;
END;
/
```

Esse comando é no `PL/SQL`, e eu não entendo como faze-lo no `SQL server`, não sei se é a mesma coisa ou algo muda.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O sql server não tem o `FOR LOOP`, em vez disso ele usar o [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms178642.aspx) , para isso você tem que criar variáveis como contador.

Seu código ficar assim.

```
declare @V_EXTERNO int = 1
declare @V_INTERNO int = 1

BEGIN
    WHILE @V_EXTERNO < 21   
    BEGIN
        print 'Contador externo: ' + cast(@V_EXTERNO as varchar(10));
        WHILE @V_INTERNO < 6        
        BEGIN
             print 'Contador interno: ' + cast(@V_INTERNO as varchar(10));
             SET @V_INTERNO = @V_INTERNO + 1;
        END;
       SET @V_EXTERNO = @V_EXTERNO + 1;
       SET @V_INTERNO = 1;
    END;
END;
```

Answer (score 5):

No *SQL SERVER* não há `FOR LOOP`, você deve simulá-lo usando `WHILE LOOP`.

Sintaxe básica;

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
BEGIN
   {...statements...}
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

**cnt_total**; O número de vezes que você deseja que WHILE LOOP rode. 
**statements**; As declarações do código que será executado a cada passagem do WHILE LOOP.

Veja esse exemplo abaixo;

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 10
BEGIN
   PRINT 'StackOverflow';
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

PRINT 'Feito';
GO
```